# RSK and $S_n$ character values

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory

Consider the symmetric group $S_n$ and its irreducible representation $\pi_\lambda: S_n \longrightarrow \text{GL}\big( V_\lambda\big)$ associated to a partition $\lambda$ of $n$. Recall that a basis vector of $V_\lambda$ can be constructed for each standard Young tableau of shape $\lambda$ --- and the action of $S_n$ on these basis elements can be described combinatorially by viewing them as complete chains in the Young lattice. 
Now given a permutation 
$w \in S_n$ let $T \times \acute{T}$ be the pair of standard Young tableaux of shape $\mu$ attached to $w$ under the RSK correspondence; $\mu$ here is another partition of $n$ as well.

**Question:** How can the character value $\chi^\lambda (g) \, := \ \text{tr} \, \Big[ \pi_\lambda ( w ) \Big]$ be interpreted/calculated using the ingredients coming from RSK --- i.e. in terms of $\mu$, $T$, and $\acute{T}$ ? For example: Can the vanishing of this character value at least be detected from $\lambda$ and $\mu$ --- for instance from the values of the Kostka numbers $K_{\lambda \mu}$ or $K_{\mu \lambda}$ ?

danks, Ines

Comment: I have never understood the supposedly central relevance of RSK to representation theory. For all I know, RSK yields an equality between some numbers (which equality can also be proven in simpler ways), which can then be used to shortcut certain arguments in representation theory (e.g., by showing that an injective map must be bijective because the dimensions of domain and target are equal). I have never seen the RSK algorithm itself feature in representation theory. I would love to be proven wrong!